# Dynamic pivot Values in a static chart

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, filter, match, vlookup

I want to enter amount values from a dynamic pivot table into a static table.

I have attached a list as an example.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MLgrWesrFg4mEJosfBqDgehOOVY4hPvrlEyQ01sM1qE/edit?usp=sharing

In the pivot table you can filter e.g. by years or months.

What I have managed to do is to filter it correctly by years. But with the entry in the correct month field I do not get further.
Currently, when I select a month, it writes the data in the first fields and not in the correct month field.
My current formula looks like this:

=IF($B$3=$B$23;B24;IF($B$3=$C$23;C24;IF($B$3=$D$23;D24;IF($B$3=$E$23;E24;0))))

What I want to achive is that the values are sorted in the correct month. Currently he pasts all into the first cells. Even If I select month like June,July, August. He posts it in January, February and March
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to reference pivot table you can just do:

```
={A23:F36}
```

[image]

dynamically:

```
=OFFSET(A23;;;COUNTA(A23:A); COUNTA(A23:23))
```

[image]

---

or:

```
=INDEX(VLOOKUP(A4:A16&"♦"&B3:F3; SPLIT(FLATTEN({SUBSTITUTE(
 TEXT(A24:A44&1; "mmmm"); 1; )&"♦"&B23:F23&"×"&B24:B44}); "×"); 2; ))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, i think i was unclear. So I edited the post